# How to copy file from one folder to another folder in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to copy pdf file from one folder 
 
i.e `/pub/media/xyz` to another `/pub/media/abc` programmatically. 
And create target folder if does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the function `copyFile()` from `Magento\Framework\Filesystem;`

```
  use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
  public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite('media');
    }
    
    $result = $this->mediaDirectory->copyFile(
        $this->getPath(self::TMP_SUBDIR, $filename),
        $this->getPath($subdirToSave, $filename)
    );
```

Comment: exception throws Class module\modulename\Controller\Vendors\Import\File does not exist in [module\modulename\Controller\Vendors\Import\Run\Interceptor]

Comment: Please, run 'rm -rf generated/" and try again

Comment: already run this command

Comment: can  you help me with object manager temporary ?

Comment: @kimnana, There is a typo mistake. use `Filesystem $backendFile` instead of `File $backendFile`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya  can  you please help me , where is  $filesystem is defined.

Comment: I have updated this answer. Please try with updated code. `Filesystem` is added in `__construct` function.

Comment: Thank you ! its work for me . there was my extension module issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cp()` function of class `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File`

```
 protected $_fileSystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $filesystemIo
    ) {
        $this->filesystemIo = $filesystemIo;
    }

    public function execute(){
    $filePath  = '/var/www/html/pub/media/imagesName.jpg';//source file
    $copyFileFullPath  = '/var/www/html/pub/media/folderName/newImagesName.jpg'; // destination file

    $filePath = $this->filesystemIo->cp($filePath, $copyFileFullPath);
}
```

Comment: actually , I tried this code at morning . but this doesn't worked.

Comment: @kimnana, there is one typo mistake please make it correct `$this->filesystemIo->cp`.
I have checked and its working fine at my end

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal, what if already file exist in destination directory?

Comment: Pretty useful for copying from a root dir to another (eg.: var/ to pub/media)